# Modifying a batch file from another batch file

Tags: batch-file, echo

I am trying to create a batch file that updates another batch file. This is what I got.

Waiter.bat

```
@echo off
set /p Waiter="What would you like to eat? "
Call Menu.bat %Waiter%
Pause
```

Menu.bat

```
@echo off
if /i "%1=="Pizza echo "Cheesy goodness"
if not "%1=="Pizza "goto Add              <----------------------------------
goto EOF                                                                    |                            
                                                                            |
:Add                                                                        |
set /p Add="%1 is not in our menu. Would you like to add it? "              |
if /i %Add%==yes goto next                                                  |
if /i %Add%==no goto EOF                                                    |
                                                                            |
:next                                                                       |       
set /p Add1="What is %1? "                                                  |
echo >> "if /i "%1=%1" "echo %Add1" -----------------------------------------
pause
goto EOF
```

How do I make it add the new menu item under the

```
if /i "%1=="Pizza echo "Cheesy goodness"
```

Comment: Do you want to permanently change the external file or simply build a list of menu options (and start again next time the main batch is run)?

Comment: @Magoo I want it to permanently change it, so when I get back to it, say a day from now, it would remember it. So even if I leave the batch file, it saves the new menu items permanently.

Comment: @Magoo So yes, I do want it to change the external file permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that migt work - it doesn't change the batch file...

**menu.bat**

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
@echo off
set /p Waiter="What would you like to eat? "
Call q28612146_Menu.bat "%Waiter%"
Pause
GOTO :EOF
```

Note: The batchfile called is simply `q28612146_Menu.bat` for my convenience. You call it what you like - Ikeep all data relating to SO question 28612146 together on my machine.

Note that I've enclosed the parameter supplied to the menu batch in quotes, which will allow you to use spaces if you like (like "Filet mignon")

**q28612146_Menu.bat**

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:begin
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=|" %%a IN (q28612146.txt) DO IF /i "%%a"=="%~1" ECHO %%b&GOTO :EOF 

:again
set /p Add="%~1 is not in our menu. Would you like to add it? " 
if /i "%Add%"=="yes" goto next
if /i "%Add%"=="no" goto :EOF
GOTO again

:next
set /p Add1="What is %1? "
>>q28612146.txt echo %~1^|%Add1%
pause
GOTO begin
```

I used a file named `q28612146.txt` containing this data for my testing.

```
Pizza|Cheesy goodness
```

The batch reads the file, putting the first "token" (before the delimiter "|") into `%%a` and the description into `%%b`. If there's a match against the supplied parameter (case-insensitive) then the description part in `%%b` is `echo`ed and we exit (note the colon - `:eof` means 'end of this batch file')

Then you ask the question, then if you want to add, ask for the description. I've also added a loop back to `again` for the case that the response is neither `yes` nor `no`.

Note the use of quotes in the `if` statements - we have no control over what is typed, so quoting the response affords some protection in case the user responds with something including a space (the protection is incomplete). The other side must also be quoted because the two strings must *exactly* match.
Then `echo` the new item and description to the data file - the caret (<kbd>^</kbd>) tells batch that the pipe is part of the data, not the instruction `echo` - and `pauses`. I chose to return to the label `begin` to read and the response from the file.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me, introduced me to a lot of new stuff and fixed my problem perfectly.

Comment: So what it is doing is logging all menu items into q28612146.txt. Then q28612146_Menu.bat looks in that text file for menu items right?

Comment: But what if I have in q28612146.txt multiple items? Like under "Pizza|Cheesy goodness" is  "Filet mignon|succulent meat"  and then the line under that "Bread|Dough" does the for /f command look through multiple lines for menu items?

Comment: Yes. That is the purpose of the `for f` - it searches the file - and adding the new item using the add-item facility simply appends a new line to the textfile in the form "Bread|Dough"